# why equality comparison of std::list can not pass compile while the T is EqualityComparable

Tags: c++, list, stl, equality

I need to compare if two list equal, so I write down following codes in my VS2005 project

```
#include <list>

class sitesInfo
{
public:
    bool operator==(const sitesInfo &rh)
    {
        return this->a == rh.a;
    }
private:
    int a;
};

int _tmain(int argc, _TCHAR* argv[])
{
    std::list<sitesInfo> list1;
    std::list<sitesInfo> list2;

    bool ret = (list1 == list2);

    return 0;
}
```

here `sitesInfo` is EqualityComparable, which is what is required in the c++ standard:

Table 96 — Container requirements

[image]

Why do I get following compile error which prevent me from comparing two list?

```
vs2005\vc\include\xutility(2476) : error C2678: binary '==' : no operator found which takes a left-hand operand of type 'const sitesInfo' (or there is no acceptable conversion)
d:\my documents\visual studio 2005\projects\test\test\test.cpp(10): could be 'bool sitesInfo::operator ==(const sitesInfo &)'
        while trying to match the argument list '(const sitesInfo, const sitesInfo)'
1>        e:\program files\vs2005\vc\include\xutility(2602) : see reference to function template instantiation 'std::pair<_Ty1,_Ty2> std::_Mismatch<_InIt1,_InIt2,std::forward_iterator_tag>(_InIt1,_InIt1,_InIt2,_InItCats,std::_Range_checked_iterator_tag)' being compiled
        with
        [
            _Ty1=std::list<sitesInfo>::_Const_iterator<false>,
            _Ty2=std::list<sitesInfo>::_Const_iterator<true>,
            _InIt1=std::list<sitesInfo>::_Const_iterator<false>,
            _InIt2=std::list<sitesInfo>::_Const_iterator<true>,
            _InItCats=std::forward_iterator_tag
        ]
        e:\program files\vs2005\vc\include\xutility(2674) : see reference to function template instantiation 'bool std::_Equal<std::list<_Ty>::_Const_iterator<_Secure_validation>,_InIt2,std::_Iter_random_helper<_Cat1,_Cat2>::_Iter_random_cat>(_InIt1,_InIt1,_InIt2,_InItCats,std::_Range_checked_iterator_tag)' being compiled
       with
                _Ty=sitesInfo,
            _Secure_validation=false,
            _InIt2=std::list<sitesInfo>::_Const_iterator<true>,
            _Cat1=std::list<sitesInfo>::_Const_iterator<true>::iterator_category,
            _Cat2=std::list<sitesInfo>::_Const_iterator<true>::iterator_category,
            _InIt1=std::list<sitesInfo>::_Const_iterator<false>,
            _InItCats=std::_Iter_random_helper<std::list<sitesInfo>::_Const_iterator<true>::iterator_category,std::list<sitesInfo>::_Const_iterator<true>::iterator_category>::_Iter_random_cat
        ]
        e:\program files\vs2005\vc\include\list(1261) : see reference to function template instantiation 'bool std::equal<std::list<_Ty>::_Const_iterator<_Secure_validation>,std::list<_Ty>::_Const_iterator<_Secure_validation>>(_InIt1,_InIt1,_InIt2)' being compiled
        with
        [
            _Ty=sitesInfo,
            _Secure_validation=true,
            _InIt1=std::list<sitesInfo>::_Const_iterator<true>,
            _InIt2=std::list<sitesInfo>::_Const_iterator<true>
        ]
        d:\my documents\visual studio 2005\projects\test\test\test.cpp(23) : see reference to function template instantiation 'bool std::operator ==<sitesInfo,std::allocator<_Ty>>(const std::list<_Ty> &,const std::list<_Ty> &)' being compiled
        with
        [
            _Ty=sitesInfo
        ]
```

I can only get it to compile by defining a global `operator==` whose parameter type is `const sitesInfo&`

```
bool operator==(const sitesInfo &rh, const sitesInfo &rs)
```

Answer (score 3):

The issue with your member `operator==` is it is not marked `const`.  When `std::list` checks for equality it does so against two `const` elements.  That means that your `operator==` is ignored as it is not marked as `const` so it cannot be called on a `const` object.

To fix this we simply mark the function as `const` like

```
bool operator==(const sitesInfo &rh) const
{
    return this->a == rh.a;
}
```

And now it will [compile and run](http://coliru.stacked-crooked.com/a/35d81a4da587a366)

The free function works as free functions do not have a `const` qualification and it takes two `const` objects.  If you had

```
bool operator==(sitesInfo &rh, sitesInfo &rs)
```

Then that would fail to compile as you are trying to remove the constness of the objects.

Answer (score 1):

Read the error carefully. Your operator :

```
 bool operator==(const sitesInfo &rh)
{
    return this->a == rh.a;
}
```

is ok for non-const objects and any right hand side, but for const objects you have to provide an operator like this:

```
 bool operator==(const sitesInfo &rh) const
{
    return this->a == rh.a;
}
```

The reason why the operator has to be const is that lists operator `==` has works on `const list`s:

```
bool operator==( const list& lhs, const list& rhs ); // template parameters 
                                                     // omitted for the sake of clarity
```

thus it can only call the `const` version of its elements comparison operator.

Comment: very interesting about your bug related with the const and order, but still not quite understand. what's the comparison order and Why the const(means not modifiable) will make the result independent with the order?

Comment: @LiuNick the lists comparison is implemented by looping through the single elements. If the comparison of the single elements was not const almost anything could happen. In particular comparing two elements could change their value which would make the whole comparison rather meaningless. However in the meantime I have my doubts against my argumentation, and a much simpler argument is that the lists `==` operator takes two `const list&`s thus it can only call a `const` operator for the elements

Comment: @tobi303 While logically that is true you can make members of the class `mutable` and change them in `const` functions.  The compiler just expects a `const` member function as it calls the operator on a `const` version of the elements.

Comment: @NathanOliver I was already thinking about that, well if you really want there is always a way too shoot yourself in the foot, otherwise it wouldnt be C++ ;). I realized that what I wrote is actually rather unrelated to the case of lists `operator ==` and edited my answer.

Comment: @NathanOliver but I was right, that that is the reason of requiring the comparison function to be const in the case of sorting, right? Because I was really wondering why that would be the case. I mean when sorting a vector, the vector itself is definitely not const...

Comment: @tobi303 I guess it depends.  If my equality operator added 1 to every elements then I could use that and the comparison will still work as I did the same change equally to all of the elements.  If it is a random change then yes you have no idea if things will sort correctly.